# New macro for math symbols

Tags: fonts

I want to increase the size of these math symbols for the `\usepackage{tgheros}` pack I'm using. Or can we recode each of them? Is it possible to write a macro for this?
[image]
This is not working for `+` symbol:

```
\makeatletter
\mathchardef\standardplus=\mathcode`+
\DeclareRobustCommand{\tauyecoplus}{%
  \mathbin{\mathpalette\tauyeco@plus\relax}%
}
\newcommand{\tauyeco@plus}[2]{%
  \raisebox{0.13\height}{\scalebox{0.95}{$\m@th#1\standardplus$}}%
}
\begingroup\lccode`~=`+ \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\tauyecoplus
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`+="8000 }
\makeatother
```

My code for the text in the image above:

```
\documentclass[11pt,A5paper]{exam}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{tgheros}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{mathastext}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\begin{document}
$x+y-z=c<d>c\neq b$
\end{document}
```

New code and image with help from David Carlisle:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tgheros}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{mathastext}
\makeatletter
\mathchardef\standardplus=\mathcode`+
\DeclareRobustCommand{\tauyecoplus}{%
  \mathbin{\mathpalette\tauyeco@plus\relax}%
}
\newcommand{\tauyeco@plus}[2]{%
  \raisebox{-0.15\height}{\scalebox{1.6}{$\m@th#1\standardplus$}}%
}
\begingroup\lccode`~=`+ \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\tauyecoplus
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`+="8000 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$x+3-z=c<d>c\neq b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: your question isn't very clear as you provide the macro you ask for in the question, so what is your question? If you add your first block of code to the preamble in the second block and add  `graphicx` package to define `\scalebox`  then + gets redefined in math mode to be 95% of its original size.

Comment: what do you mean by "normal latex" here?

Comment: I meant original tex of text. @DavidCarlisle

Comment: That's not the macro I want in the question. I gave it as an example. For the tgheros font I want. I edited my question again sorry for the confusion. @DavidCarlisle

Comment: but that macro applies to any font, if you add it to your document using tgheros then it applies to that. Now you have deleted the code, what can we do other than add it back as an answer?

Comment: I re-added the code but unfortunately it doesn't work in the document.

Comment: Posting the code as two fragments people need to join together just makes it harder to test. The code as posted shrinks + to 95% of its size, I guess you want to make it bigger so change 0.95 to 1.1 or whatever size you want

Comment: Yes sir it worked. How can I do it for other symbols? Can't we write a collaborative macro for all of them?